# Annotate table view on iPad Pro with Pencil

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

I'm building an app for the iPad Pro that has a UITableView showing a catalog with items. There are many catalogs each with 1-thousands of items.

**Goal**

I would like to find out how to (best) make it possible to annotate stuff in the UITableView using Pencil so that the user can scroll with the finger. Also, what the user has drawn is persisted in the data model.

Let me explain what I have tried.

**Single UIView**

I put a single UIView on top of a custom UITableView that overrides the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Canceled` functions and filters on `touch.type == UITouchType.Stylus` to know when it's the finger and when it's Pencil. That works but it's not a good solution as the image will be huge and not even possible to put for some catalogs with too many items.

**Per row a UIView**

Works well with a large catalog, but a problem came up with not being able to draw across rows which must be possible. I didn't yet find a way to keep the gesture across different views. Is this possible or is there some kind of workaround?

**Fixed UIView on screen**

Follows when scrolling, easy to draw across anything, but unclear and difficult to fix drawn stuff to table coordinates as well as persist it. It didn't feel right as it seemed overly complex to maybe have the screen-sized canvas to follow and anything drawn is converted to an UIImageView for the rows it spans and persisted there...this is where I am now and I can show some code if this approach makes sense.

Is there a better approach to this as it seems to me this should be a very natural need now with Pencil, i.e. to annotate and persist in a table view.

Has anyone done something like this or is there something I have overlooked? Maybe some kind of sparse UIImageView so I can have a single across a massive table?

I'm looking for a good solution and example code depending on how involved the solution is.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So to clarify, the items in the table are ordered in a fixed way so one can use that to persist the drawn/annotated stuff as partials.

Generally, the drawings/annotations can be persisted as anything from 1 to N images. One image is in many cases too big as the items are many thousands, N images means there is a border where a gesture is interrupted and that is not ideal for usability as the drawing isn't continuous (unless this is possible to solve which would be great).

The data model can be catalog [ -> pages ] -> items but I would not like to have a page concept as it (longer reason short) makes the items per page smaller and the whole point is to maximize the items to it's easier to annotate.

Comment: Is a annotation connected to a single item in the table view? If the order of items in the table view changes should the annotations follow the new order?

Comment: Yeah, very good question. This is of course all related to this specific case and the order is fixed and will not change. Annotation does not have to be connected to a specific row/item but could be if it helps to persist (small images versus bigger images?)

Comment: But of course, the annotations are related to the items/rows. I.e. you mark something or comment something for that specific row/item. Further you might want to mark/annotate a series of items so hence the drawing/annotation should span multiple rows/items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so nobody seems to have done this.

I have it working now with per row a drawing canvas that also persists as an image. The main issue with this was making drawing continuous and uninterrupted across table rows.

The way I did it was to use `hitTest` in my custom Table View class to catch the touches:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
{
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event) {
        if let sv = result.superview {
            if sv.isKindOfClass(TableHeaderView) {
                return result
            }
        }
        return self
    }
    return nil
}
```

...and then in the `touches*` functions I disable/enable scrolling if it's pencil and then delegate to the corresponding cell to draw and persist.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if touch.type == UITouchType.Stylus {
            scrollEnabled = false

            let location = touch.locationInView(self)
            // find underlying cell -> call drawTouches
            for visibleCell in visibleCells {
                if let cell = visibleCell {
                    if CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, location) {
                        cell.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea is to have the overall control in the table view to keep a gesture continuous. The other way to achieve this would have been with that single screen-fixed draw canvas and delegate to table cells. The thing to also care about is scrolling to in my case allow for finger scroll and pencil draw. The `UIScrollView` that `UITableView` is derived from catches gestures so one needs to not delay gestures in the table view class.

```
    delaysContentTouches = false
```

Works very well, but not sure if there's a nicer way so please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go about it in the following way.

```
[draw layer]
[annotation layer]
[table view]
```

Three layers, with the table view on the bottom. 
The top layer is fixed and used for drawing. As soon as a annotation has been drawn it will be moved to the annotation layer which is also fixed.

When the drawing is moved into the annotation layer it should be translated into the tableview layers coordinate system (content offset in table view + offset in draw layer)

As soon as the tableview is scrolled the annotation layers coordinate system is translated with `CGAffineTransform` which will move all sublayers so that the annotations will 'scroll' with the tableview. To clarify, the annotation layers coordinate system should always be in sync with the content offset of the tableview.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not addressing everything I explained I need.